# Creating new static sprites for Warhammer 40K Armageddon Pc Game

Tags: 3d, rendering, sprites, modding

I want to create new unit sprites for the Warhammer 40K Armageddon pc game.

Game uses simple 3D static PNG sprites facing 6 different direction for all units. They don't animate in game, just pictures (as shown in link).

If I simply copy already-made sprites and just rename them with my own liking, I can integrate to game easily (with adding strings, sound and animation files etc.). But I want to create my own unique sprites. I know this can be done because other people already did this (I of course tried to contact them through game forums and steam at first but couldn't succeeded, so I wanted to ask here).

How can I make these sprites?

P.S. I don't have any kind of modelling experience, but I'm a coder.

Some of already-made sprites: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xLdA.jpg

Comment: Are you asking how to make a (orthographic) screenshot from existing models? Or are you asking how to make a 3d model? Or how to draw a png?

Comment: Or, as another option, have you already created your images, and you're asking about how to make the game recognize your new sprites as a distinct image set, without overwriting existing units in the game?

Comment: @Peter, sorry but I have no idea what I exactly want to know because of no experience in modelling. I just want to learn how to make new graphics like in the link. But it must be PNG to make transparent background because in game, those pngs are being used as a attacking/moving units.

Comment: If you just want to draw a png GIMP is one of several possible starting points. If you want to create a 3D model which you later want to make a png from, Blender is a starting point. Neither of these are the best possible programs for the job but they are free, useful for much more, and get the job done.

Comment: @DMGregory, I think I don't have any problem of recognizing new sprites because I can rename them for my liking and attach to my new units with different stats. And I can use them with existing units in the game at same time. For example: There is a unit called "Predator Annihilator". I can use this unit's graphic with the name of "Predator Infernus" without any problem. But it will use same graphic so it won't be a graphically distinct unit.

Comment: @Peter, thank you for fast response... Yes there won't be a "best software" to make this because of inexperience of me. But yeah I will try GIMP definetly. I did some research last night so I think most new unit model makers are using GIMP, not proffessional 3D modeling softwares. And I assume it is not very difficult process because there are 2 mods which contains 70 new models and animations and 94 new models and animations. Making 94 new models from scratch using pro 3D modelling should have been very exhausting and money wasting, so it should have been easy... Still of course, I'm not sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could still use a copy of the original sprites and either edit them by using them as a template (like erasing the sprite's weapon and drawing your own). Or completely erase the sprites and draw new ones and keep the same dimensions. So if the sprite is 32x64 pixels, any image that is that size will be used in place of the original image.

Hope that helps

Comment: Yes, exactly this idea came to my mind last night when I was about to sleep =)  But still if I can learn how to make completely new models, it will be the best for me. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 0):

I've opened another model, cut any section I want, opened an image I want to modify, pasted onto it, did some smoothing/reshaping etc and done. Top is original model, below is sponson (side) mounted heavy bolter. I did same modifying to all 6 directions.
Thank you for ideas and answers.

[image: original model]

[image: modified model with sponson mounted heavy bolter weapon]